# Click on a button opens a new window which is giving login page

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am logging into a website and in which there is a button which we have to click which will open a new window.
When we are clicking on the button through the script it is giving login page not the page I am expecting.

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="Legacy Reports"]')))
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Legacy Reports"]').click()
```

These are the lines of code which I am using to click on the button.

Comment: Are you sure you have `input[value="Legacy Reports"]` only one element in your document ?

Comment: we are Logging in through the script on a website and after selecting some drop down and other controls there is a button called "Legacy Report" is getting clicked which is opening a pop-up window where we need to select few more dropdown. The new pop-up window is rendering to the login page, not the page which we are expecting.
If clicking on the button "Legacy Report" manually it is opening the expected page in the new window.

I tried waiting for 15 minutes if there is an issue and then again click on the button but still, the issue is coming or start from the beginning.

Comment: Can you share the url, or add some html in your question?

Comment: If you are using IE browser, then kill all the existing IE process and then run the script.

Comment: I am Sorry, unfortunately, It a financial website I can't share. Please suggest me some different approach which I can try

Comment: @luckygupta Did u try closing all the IE instances prior launching the application?

Comment: for chrome, f12, go to console and type the following: `$x("//input[@value='Legacy Reports']")` how many results are there?